# Merging branch and sub-branch back to master

Tags: git

I have limited knowledge of git.

I have created a branch B1 from master, made some edits and committed to this branch.

I want to create another branch B2 from B1, I make some edits in B2

And I also want to commit and push B2 (with edits from B2 and B1) back to master

How do I do this, the documentation assumes you are always creating a branch from master , not another branch. I apologise for my git stupidity.

Comment: `master` is only a name. Merging a branch into another branch works irrespective of how the branches are named.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tayfun's answer is fundamentally correct.  If you want more conceptual background on why:

The documentation should not be making assumptions about branching from master (at least not if you're looking at canonical git documentation; obviously I don't know what docs you're looking at).  Examples may typically start from `master` just because they're simple examples, but the thing to understand is this:

There is nothing special about `master`.

A branch is a branch; one of them just happens to be there first, and by convention it's called `master`.

Additionally, git has no memory of "parent branches" or anything like that.  At any given time, you can focus on the current commit topology.  So:

> I have created a branch B1 from master, made some edits and committed to this branch.

```
x -- O <--(master)
      \
       A <--(B1)
```

> I want to create another branch B2 from B1, I make some edits in B2

```
x -- O <--(master)
      \
       A <--(B1)
        \
         B <--(B2)
```

At this point, git doesn't know or care that `B2` was "created from `B1`".  Instead of following the above steps, you could have said:

- Create `B2` from master
- Make some changes and commit (creating `A`)
- Make some changes and commit (creating `B`)
- Go back to `A` and create branch `B1`

and everything would be the same.

> And I also want to commit and push B2 (with edits from B2 and B1) back to master

Here your terminology is confused.

To `push` is to update a remote repository ref.  Typically your remote could have a branch corresponding to each local branch.  Although git is very flexible and you *could* use push in a different way, it still doesn't seem like what you mean here.

To combine the changes from one local branch into another local branch is to `merge`.  (There are actually a few ways to go about this, but conceptually the most straightforward is a merge...)

Also, this touches on a common misconception about branches in git - that a change "belongs to" this branch or that branch.  In many source control systems that may be true, but in git it's not.  Instead a change either is, or is not, "reachable" from a branch (or other ref); and a change can be (often is) reachable from many refs.

(Essentially a branch (or other ref) is a pointer to a commit; that commit is reachable from the ref.  If that commit has a parent, the parent commit is reachable.  This continues recursively through parent pointers, so that the entire history leading up to a ref is reachable from that ref.)

So going back to the diagram

```
x -- O <--(master)
      \
       A <--(B1)
        \
         B <--(B2)
```

What you've described is that `A` and `B` should be merged to `master`.  Because `A` and `B` are exactly the commits that are reachable from `B2` but not reachable from `master`, this is as simple as

```
git checkout master
git merge B2
```

Note that by default git will take a shortcut here, by performing a "fast-forward" instead of a true merge.  This can be done because `master` has no changes that are unreachable from `B2`.  In that situation, git can just update `master` to moving it to the same commit as `B2`.

```
x -- O -- A <--(B1)
           \
            B <--(B2)(master)
```

You may not want git to do that.  (Some branch/merge strategies call for preservation of branch topology.)  In that case you could say

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff B2
```

which would give you

```
x -- O --------------- M <--(master)
      \               /
       A <--(B1)     /
        \           /
         B --------/
         ^
       (B2)
```

where `M` is a "merge commit".  If there were additional changes reachable from `master` but unreachable from `B2`, the merge commit would combine those with the changes from `A` and `B`.

Either way, `B1` remains pointed at `A` and `B2` remains pointed at `B`, so they are both fully reachable from `master`.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing preventing you from merging any branch back to master. That branch could be branched from master or any other branch. Simply do:

```
git checkout master
git merge B2
```

Try this. You can always do `git reset --hard origin/master` if you want to reset it to be like origin (assuming your remote repo is called origin, or if you don't have a remote you can also provide a commit hash).

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a brief explanation of how `git` works so that you understand.
Let's create a repository in `temp/` folder

```
$ cd temp
$ git init
```

Now, create a file hello.txt with following text

```
in master
```

Save it, commit changes and check your branch name using

```
$ git add hello.txt
$ git commit -m 'committed in master'
$ git branch
* master                                  # the output
```

Ok, now you create a branch names `B1`

```
$ git checkout -b B1
```

Now check what the `hello.txt` has inside it.

```
$ cat hello.txt
in master
```

It has same text as master branch. Now edit the file and add some text

```
in master
in B1
```

You save the file in **B1** branch and it has the updated data. Commit the changes and create a new branch while being in **B1**

```
$ git add hello.txt
$ git commit -m 'committed in B1'
```

Create a branch names `B2` without going back to master

```
$ git checkout -b B2
```

If you check the content of hello.txt in B2 you will have same text as in B2, because the branch B2 is originated from branch B1. And now if you go back to master branch and see the content of hello.txt you will find ==> `in master` only, changes in branches **B1 and B2** will not affect **master branch**
Now change the content of hello.txt

```
in master
in B1
in B2
```

Save and commit the changes.

*Now coming back to your question*, you want to **merge** (*Not push*) changes from *B2* branch to *B1*. You can go back to branch *B1* to do that.

```
$ git branch B1                        # To change the branch to B1
$ git merge B2                         # It will merge changes made in B2 to B1
```

Now check the content of *hello.txt* in **B1**. Nice. Right?
Similarly go to master branch and merge the changes made in **B1** to master. And there you have it.